# How to avoid "Warning, empty ricardian clause file" warnings?

Tags: ricardian, eosio-cpp, code

When executing

```
eosio-cpp -I include -o eosio.token.wasm src/eosio.token.cpp --abigen
```

over the eosio.token smart contract I get the following warnings:

```
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, action <create> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <issue> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <retire> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <transfer> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <open> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <close> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <create> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <issue> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <retire> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <transfer> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <open> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <close> does not have a ricardian contract
```

Is there any way to suppress those warnings?
I tried `-w` but didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  It looks like what you said should work, but if it's not, I don't see another flag that would do that.

```
-w  | - Suppress all warnings
```

They (the warnings) were there at the beginning, then they went away, and now it looks like they're back.

This is a good thing because it will remind developers to add them.  Technically, the current constitution says they should be on all contracts, but that is obviously not being enforced.  In the future, it likely will be.

---

### Article VII - Open Source

> Each Member who makes available a smart contract on this blockchain
>   shall be a Developer. Each Developer shall offer their smart contracts
>   via a free and open source license, and **each smart contract shall be
>   documented with a Ricardian Contract** stating the intent of all parties
>   and naming the Arbitration Forum that will resolve disputes arising
>   from that contract.

[Link](https://github.com/EOS-Mainnet/governance/blob/master/eosio.system/eosio.system-clause-constitution-rc.md)

---

If there is a way, **@tbfleming** or **@sandw1ch** would know in the E[OS Developers Telegram](https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg)